# How to mock an aws library GlueContext using python unittest

Tags: python, aws-glue

unable to mock GlueContext from aws glue

I have these lines of code

```
sc = SparkContext()
gluecontext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = gluecontext.spark_session
```

How to mock gluecontext using python unittest?

[How to mock in a python unittest a library not installed locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919705/how-to-mock-in-a-python-unittest-a-library-not-installed-locally)

Comment: Glue has development ends point for that.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint.html

Answer (score 2):

One way is to download Glue libs and Spark to the root of your project (or configure as you like)

```
wget https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/archive/glue-1.0.zip
wget https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-1.0/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8.tgz
unzip glue-1.0.zip -d $PROJECT_ROOT
tar -xf spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8.tgz -C $PROJECT_ROOT
export SPARK_HOME=$PROJECT_ROOT/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8
```

Then simply mock gluecontext

```
from mock import patch
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('awsglue.context.GlueContext')
    @patch('awsglue.utils.getResolvedOptions', side_effect=mock_get_resolved_options)
    def test_method(self, mock_resolve_options, mock_glue_context):
        <your code>
```

Submit tests locally

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0/bin/gluepytest $PROJECT_ROOT/tests/
```