# Writing Unit test for Glue Code with DynamicFrame

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytest, aws-glue

I am looking to write unit test for glue code and am not sure how to mock the glueContext and assert the dynamicFrame.

```
def test_set_dynamic_frame(self):
 newRow = spark.createDataFrame([('test2', '24/12/1991', 'abcd', '24/12/1991', 'ábcd', '24/12/1991', '1')])
 df = self.df.union(newRow)

 print('\nDynamic Frame used to Set: ')
 df.show()

 self.gluedbreader.set_dynamic_frame(df)

 print('Set Dynamic Frame: ')
 self.gluedbreader.get_dynamic_frame.show()
 self.assertEqual(self.gluedbreader.get_dynamic_frame, df)
```

As you see I am using spark dataframe and then trying to assert to dynamic data frame.

Is there anyway to create a dynamicFrame on the go as spark dataframe. Also anyway I can mock the glue context so that it can be used in other test functions.

Comment: See this answer for mocking Glue Context - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458399/3760804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock an aws library GlueContext using python unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443713/how-to-mock-an-aws-library-gluecontext-using-python-unittest)